# Am I finding curl correct?

Tags: field-theory, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields, curl

I have a field $E(x,y)=2xi+yj$, and want to find the curl. I do this by the next way:

$rotE=i\dfrac{d(2x+y)}{dx}+j\dfrac{d(2x+y)}{dy}$ and get $2i+j$

Is it correct?

Comment: What you're computing there seems to be the gradient, not the curl.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You mean, if instead of vector function will be just a scalar function $f(x,y)=2x+y$ then $\nabla * 2x+y=3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's wrong. We have $$\nabla\times E=(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}i+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}j)\times E=\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}k-\dfrac{\partial 2x}{\partial y}k=0$$

Comment: What is $k$ and why minus?

Comment: Well! It is the unit vector along z-axis. We have that $i\times j=k$ because the Cartesian coordinates is orthonormal and anticlockwise.

Comment: Wait a moment, I have vector field in two-dimensional space, there is no z axis. We have $i\dfrac{d}{dx}+j\dfrac{d}{dy} \times 2xi+yj$. Why did You get minus, and why did You multiply I and j orts?

Comment: Why not? We have to multiply all the vectors pairwise including $i$ and $j$. Also $v\times v$ becomes zero by using a simple argument and $i\times j$ should be a vector which is normal to both $i$ and $j$. What does this make from $i\times j$?

Comment: So, You mean if I have $(i1+j1)\times(i2+j2)$ the result will be $i1\times i2+i1\times j2+j1\times i1+j1\times j2$?

Comment: Are the 1s and 2s coeffs?

Comment: Yes, like $2x$ or $\dfrac{d}{dx}$

Comment: Then that you wrote is write though there are some typo

Comment: $(i1+j1)\times(i2+j2)$ the result will be $i1\times i2+i1\times j2+j1\times i2+j1\times j2$ now right?

Comment: Come on, Mohamed, You'll answer?

Comment: @Arnold, you're probably not winning Mostafa's goodwill by calling him Mohamed...

Answer (score 1):

The $2$-dimensional curl is $\operatorname {rot} E=\frac{\partial (y)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial (2x)}{\partial y}=0$.